# Shell: modifying a programs stdout

Tags: shell

I have been trying to modify the stdout of a Terraria server like this:

```sh
(([ -p ".pipe" ] || mkfifo .pipe) && (mono tModLoaderServer.exe -savedirectory ~/ -tmlsavedirectory ~/saves -modpath ~/mods < .pipe | sed 's/):/):\n/' &) && read > .pipe && rm .pipe)
```

What it is supposed to do is put a newline at the end of lines ending in `):`

The server starts as normal, but when I try to send a command, the server repeats the main menu over and over, seperated by a blank line:

```
Choose World: Terraria Server v1.3.5.2 - tModLoader v0.10.1.5
1 world1
n New World
d <number>Delete World
m Mods Menu
b Mod Browser

[...]
```

This is the same behaviour as if i would just send a newline to the console over and over again.
I suspect the "read" reads anything that is posted to the shells stdin, so it'll basically pipe the servers stdout into its stdin.

I haven't been able to find anything relating to my problem and appreciate any suggestion. I am also open for a completely different solution.

Comment: does the basic nub of your solution (`prog | sed ...`) work as you want? If not, then all the `mkfifo` etc is only getting in the way (IMHO). Good luck.

Comment: If you just want to _modify the stdout_, why do you redirect mono's standard input? And what do you intend to achieve with redirecting read's standard output, which is none?